# How can I change the page title of PDFs opened from a WordPress link which use the browser's viewer?

Tags: media-library, pdf

When you open a Media page and click the link to open an attached PDF, it uses the browser's own code to generate the HTML wrapper. And the HTML title is extracted from the PDF.

We have many documents where the PDF title is not what we want the visitor to see, eg. it will contain "Microsoft Word - " since the user generated the PDF from inside Word.

Ideally we would want to use JS or jQuery to modify the title in the browser, but since the page is outside of WordPress we cannot figure out how to do it.

Or, if there is a plugin PDF reader that would allow us to to do this, we'd like to know if such a thing is available.

Comment: Seems to have already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57192981/15638466

Comment: Thanks. But that link seems to discuss re-writing the PDF via PHP. We're trying to modify the title without having to edit the PDF. Our site has thousands of legacy PDFs with unhelpful titles and it would be onerous to edit them all.